# Implementing generic interface without specifying generic type parameter in implementation

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I would like to know if I can implement a generic interface without ever specifying the type parameter(s) in the implementing types.

For example:

Let's say I have a non-generic interface and a generic version of this interface, called IEnumItem. The implementing class should implement both the generic and the non-generic, but I don't want to specify a type parameter T for this class, since I want to be able to cast it to different implementations of this generic interface. Implementations I do not yet know. In this case, I have an enum item, which has a value that could be cast into different kinds of enum. The enum value of 1 represents 'b' in ActualEnum1 and represents 'e' in ActualEnum2. Both situations are valid in my situation.

In code:

```
    public interface IEnumItem
    {
        int Value { get; }
    }

    public interface IEnumItem<T> : IEnumItem
        where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        new T Value { get; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Implementing class, 
    /// notice that no type parameter is specified in the class implementation
    /// </summary>
    public class EnumItem : 
        IEnumItem,
        IEnumItem<T>
        where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        public int Value { get; private set; }

        T IEnumItem<T>.Value { get { return (T)(object)this.Value; } }

        public EnumItem(int value)
        {
            this.Value = value;
        }
    }

    public enum ActualEnum1
    {
        a, b, c,
    }

    public enum ActualEnum2
    {
        d, e, f,
    }

    public class UsageExample
    {
        public void Main ()
        {
            var item = new EnumItem(1);

            IEnumItem<ActualEnum1> itemAsEnum1 = (IEnumItem<ActualEnum1>)item;
            ActualEnum1 value1 = itemAsEnum1.Value; // should return 'b'

            IEnumItem<ActualEnum2> itemAsEnum2 = (IEnumItem<ActualEnum2>)item;
            ActualEnum2 value2 = itemAsEnum2.Value; // should return 'e'
        }
    }
```

Something like this is also possible; implementing this in the class:

```
        public T AsEnum<T>()
            where T : struct, IConvertible
        {
            return (T)(object)this.EnumValue;
        }
```

But ideally I would like to have the possibility of casting to 'IEnumItem<...>' as shown in the example and getting the value this way. If this is not possible, I'm okay with that, but I'm mainly curious.

Thank you!

Comment: No, it is not possible. Either you have to specifically say for which `T` you implement `IEnumItem<T>` when declaring the class, or you have to make the class generic as well. It may be that you don't want generics here.

Comment: Additionally, you can't declare conversion operators in interfaces, and thus you will only be *casting* to a different `IEnumItem<T>`, which will only work if the type is *actually* implementing that. The fact that could convert the `T` to a different type doesn't factor into this.

Comment: Also know that your `(T)(object)value` only works if the enum type in `T` is based on an `int`. If I declare an enum like this: `public enum X : byte`, it will fail at runtime with an InvalidCastException. This is hard/difficult/impossible to properly handle in generic code, which is something you should try to avoid doing. You might want to add more `Convert.ToXXX` code to first detect the underlying type for the enum, and then converting to that type.

Comment: Hi @LasseV.Karlsen , thank you for the quick and crisp response. If it is not possible, I will go with the 'AsEnum' approach. I did also try specifying the cast operator, but this did indeed result in the error that it is not possible to cast to an interface (and it does not seem to work with generics as well). Thank you also for pointing me on the boxing and casting issue, I am aware of that, but as a quick example I didn't really think this trough.